# Visual Studio fails to link mod_spnego to SSPI

Tags: visual-c++, sspi

I am trying to compile mod_spnego (http://sourceforge.net/projects/modgssapache/) with SSPI support in Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. I have managed to get the compiling itself work fine, but now I am stuck at some errors that the linker prints out:

Linking...
   Creating library 2-win32-debug/mod_spnego.lib and object 2-win32-debug/mod_spnego.exp
mod_spnego.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DeleteSecurityContext@4 referenced in function _handleSpnegoTokenSSPI
mod_spnego.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _QueryContextAttributesA@12 referenced in function _handleSpnegoTokenSSPI
mod_spnego.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _FreeContextBuffer@4 referenced in function _handleSpnegoTokenSSPI
mod_spnego.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__AcceptSecurityContext@36 referenced in function _handleSpnegoTokenSSPI
mod_spnego.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _AcquireCredentialsHandleA@36 referenced in function _handleSpnegoTokenSSPI
2-win32-debug/mod_spnego.so : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals

Looking in the source code, these methods come from Sspi.h in the Microsoft SDK. I have no idea about compiling things on Windows, so I have an easy question: What lib file contains the SSPI API? Which one do I have to link against?

By the way, at the moment, the following libs are linked:
kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

Thank you,
memminger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found it out myself: Secur32.Lib.